# Perl: joining all lines of a .txt without first one

Tags: perl, join, lines

the aim of my question is to join all lines of a file into a line, ignoring the first line. I have this code:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ /g;' file
```

It joins all lines of a file, the first one included. Do you know any way to avoid the first line?

Another way would be:

```
foreach $line (<SEQ>) {
    next if $. == 1;
    chomp $line;     
    $one .= $line; }
```

but it takes too long...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -wpe'BEGIN{<>} tr/\n/ /' file
```

though from the command line I would probably just do

```
tail -n +2 file | tr '\n' ' '
```

In a script:

```
use File::Slurp 'read_file';
my $out = read_file('filename');
$out =~ s/\A.*?\n//;
$out =~ tr/\n/ /;
```

Comment: What if I can't use File::Slurp??

Comment: why wouldn't you be able to use File::Slurp (possibly after installing it)?

Comment: If you don't want to do it the right way, there are lots of incantations for how to do it wrong; here's a *very* wrong way: `my ($out) = map~~readline!open(!((*{!$_},$/)=\$_)),"filename";`

Comment: The `tail -n +2... ` method is prefered.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe '$_="" if $.==1; s/\n/ /g;' file
```

Comment: Many thanks!! It is what I was looking for. Could you write it like it was inside a script?